# Fetch Specific Files from Parse.com

Tags: ios, file, uicollectionview, parse-platform

I am pretty confused on how to fetch specific Columns from a selected Row.

My first View is a UICollectionView that finds all objects from a Class. Once a Cell is selected you are segued to a DetailView containing another UICollectionView that will show files from that selected Row.

How do you set up the Query in order for the second CollectionView to show specific Columns of a specific Row?

Please see image. I need to show image_1, image_2, image_3... etc. in the Second CollectionView!

[image: My Data Browser]

**EDITED CODE:**

**VestimentaViewController.m**

```
#import "VestimentaViewController.h"
#import "VestimentaDetailViewController.h"

@interface VestimentaViewController ()

@end

@implementation VestimentaViewController

@synthesize imagesCollection, activityIndicator;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[self queryParseMethod];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)queryParseMethod {

[activityIndicator startAnimating];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"VestimentaView"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        vestimentaFilesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];

        [imagesCollection reloadData];
    }


}];
}

#pragma mark Collection data source

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

return 1;

}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:    (NSInteger)section {

return [vestimentaFilesArray count];

}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
VestimentaCell *cell = (VestimentaCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

PFObject *infoObject = [vestimentaFilesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.storeName.text = [infoObject objectForKey:@"cellTitle"];

cell.storeDescription.text = [infoObject objectForKey:@"descriptionTitle"];

[activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    }

return cell;

}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"vestimentaDetail"]){

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.imagesCollection indexPathForCell:sender];

    PFObject *object = [vestimentaFilesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    VestimentaDetailViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    detailViewController.vestimenta = object;
}
}


@end
```

**VestimentaViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "VestimentaCell.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>


@interface VestimentaViewController : UIViewController {

NSArray *vestimentaFilesArray;
NSMutableArray *tiendasArray;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *imagesCollection;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

@end
```

**VestimentaDetailViewController.m**

```
#import "VestimentaDetailViewController.h"
#import "VestimentaViewController.h"


@interface VestimentaDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation VestimentaDetailViewController

@synthesize imagesCollection;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[self queryParseMethod];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark Collection data source

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

return 1;

}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [filesArray count];

}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
VestimentaDetailCell *cell = (VestimentaDetailCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

PFFile *imageFile = [self.vestimenta objectForKey:@"image_1"];

[imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {
cell.imageFile.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

}
}];

return cell;

}

@end
```

**VestimentaDetailViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "VestimentaDetailCell.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>


@interface VestimentaDetailViewController : UIViewController {

NSArray *filesArray;

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) PFObject *vestimenta;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *imagesCollection;

@end
```

This will show the images of each cell Clicked but only image_1... How do I construct an array or dictionary that will show image_1, image_2, image_3 of any clicked cell (in the second or detail view controller)?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Are you asking how to construct a query that will return the highlighted row? Or are you asking how to download and display the images that are in the highlighted row?

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. Yes, what I am asking is how to construct a query of the highlighted row.

Comment: Actually, I've been getting around it and think what I need is an array of the files (columns - image_1, image_2, image_3.. etc) to be called up in the Second View and use a Reusable ImageView. is that clear?

Answer (score 2):

You could code down a function which is called on selection of row which will fire a query and put up on imageview(PFImageView) in secondViewController like,

```
-(void)settingAllImageView
{
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ImageClassName"];

 /*Could put up condition if require specific row*/

 [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error && objects.count != 0)
     {
         NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved: %@", objects);

         for(int *i=0;i<=[objects count];i--)
         {
           NSDictionary *dict = [objects objectAtIndex:i];
           PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:@"image"];
           imageView.file = file;
           /*imageView is  PFImageView*/

           /*For more than 1 images in a row you could store PFFiles in a array den use that array to load up imageView*/
         }      

   // Now tell PFImageView to download the file asynchronously
   [imageView loadInBackground];
  }
 }];
}
```

Comment: I think this will work. I do need a hand though. How do I construct an array retrieving it from parse.com?

Comment: You could have array1 for storing image1 ,array2 for image2 and so on...Then you could pass these array to second view controller and use as per your need. Also you could store all image in in array by creating a dictionary of images 1,2,3,... then use it!

Comment: I think I need to create a Dictionary bu I'm still pretty confused. I will be editing my code in this question hopefully it helps.

Comment: @adriennemhenry : You would have to explicitly call getdatainbackground method for other object key's i.e., image_2 and image_3

Comment: Create a function like below and call it before cellForItemAtIndexPath :  
-(void)filterImages
{
    /*Make **imageArray** global so you could call it in cellForItemAtIndexPath*/
    PFFile *imageFile1 = [self.object objectForKey:@"image_1"];
    [imageFile1 getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            [imageArray addObject:data];
        }
    }];

    PFFile *imageFile2 = [self.object objectForKey:@"image_2"];
    [imageFile2 getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        }
Same for imgae_3....}

Comment: So finally your imageArray will have all images.

Also I think this is not a good approach as in-case when image increase then you code inc and so explicit calls for different objecForKey which is not good.I would suggest you create a different class for it like ImageClass in which u'll have a column of images and user(pointer type). So then you will just have to fire one query to ImageClass with condition (where equal to user) that would get you all images in one go. Thus, no need of explicitly writing objectForKey:@"image_1" or @"image_2" etc. Also no need to worry for scalability.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem I had before. I have now created another class (ImageClass) which I believe it to be a better approach, same as you said and sorry for this.. but now I am confused on how to call the query. I have set it but now the images all appear the same in every cell clicked. I need it to show the images belonging to the previous clicked cell. How do I set that condition?

Comment: In imageClass you must have a unique Id(For e.g. rowId) related to images like rowId1 is related to img1,img2 and img3 where else there is rowId2 with img1 n img2 and so on. So when you click a row fire a query to ImageClass with condition including that unique Id(For e.g. P1) so then you will get ALL img related to that Id.

Comment: Query would like:-
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ImageClass"];
 
 [query whereKey:@"UNIQUE_ID_NAME" equalTo:@"ROW_ID_1"];
 /* ROW ID COULD BE SELECTED ROW */
 /* UNIQUE ID IS COLUMN NAME */
 [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
  {
    if (!error && objects.count != 0)
    {
      NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved: %@", objects);         
    }
  }];

Answer (score 0):

You don't fetch specific columns from Parse. You always fetch the whole row as a PFObject, and then you get specific properties from that object.

In your collection view, you are already showing the cellTitle. This means you already have the PFObject containing the images. You should use a PFImageView to display the images. The files are not downloaded yet, so what you  need to do is set the PFImageView file to the image_1 file etc, like this:

```
PFImageView *firstImage = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
firstImage.file = theObjectFromPreviousCollectionView[@"image_1"];
[firstImage loadInBackground];
```

"theObjectFromPreviousCollectionView" is the object corresponding to the cell you clicked. In the prepareForSegue method, you pass this object to the detail view.

Comment: I actually did that but there is where I have a memory problem. I have about 10 images per row and if I load more than 5 PFImageViews the crashes because of memory problems (each image is 1 MB at most). So I have to figure out a way to make a reusable PFImageView, that is why I was thinking of a CollectionView.

Comment: Do you know how would I have to set up the collectionView of the DetailView (Second View)?